# Clearing a form of controls for more to be added

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a standard panel which I add controls too, when the number of controls exceeds the panels size I want to clear the panel ready for the "next page" of controls which just is a clear and location reset of the buttons. Problem is when ever I clear the controls new ones will not add. Here is what I have:

```
// MDButList is the collection of controls            

ButPosX = 2; // x position of button on panel
ButPosY = 2; // y position of button on panel
PageCount = 1; // page number

for (int i = 0; i <= MDButList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    NewPOBut = MDButList[i]; // as cant ref a collection for some reason..
    if (i % 14 == 0) // panel can only hold 14
    {
        if (i < 13) // for first item (0)
            SetPOButPos(ref ButPosX, ref ButPosY, ref NewPOBut); 
            //sets the buttons point value and increments x & y
        else
        {
           panMDItems.Controls.Clear();

           ButPosX = 2;
           ButPosY = 2;

           PageCount++;

           SetPOButPos(ref ButPosX, ref ButPosY, ref NewPOBut);

           btnPrevPage.Visible = true;
           btnNextPage.Visible = true;
           labPageNum.Visible = true;

           labPageNum.Text = PageCount.ToString() + " / " + PageCount.ToString(); 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SetPOButPos(ref ButPosX, ref ButPosY, ref NewPOBut);
    }
}
```

Controls are being added to the collection and the code steps through as expected but after 14 controls I just get a blank panel nothing above a 14 control count will add? Ask if you need more info, thanks!

Comment: Does it works when the number of buttons is <14? Because I can´t see where do you increment ButPosX and ButPosY, so i guess all buttons are in the same place...

Comment: Yeah works fine upto 14 then the panel simply clears and nothing else is added. I have tried commenting out the `panMDItems.Controls.Clear();` and setting `x` & `y` to `4` to see if they overlap the buttons already there and they do..

Comment: Does SetPOButPos increment ButPosX and ButPosY? If it does, edit your question and add it. Anyway, with this code you are only going to see the last buttons because when i==14 it is going to remove the previous buttons.

Comment: That is the intention. When button 15 is added it should clear all previous and add it at the start position `2,2` so it looks like its a new page. I have managed to fix it anyway by adding `panMDItems.Controls.Add(NewPOBut);` before `SetPOButPos(ref ButPosX, ref ButPosY, ref NewPOBut);` love to know why the first 14 work without that though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was kind of bored, so i've made a sample of how i would do what you are asking for. This is my code, see if it fits you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int page = 1;
    private int pageCount = 0;
    List<Button> MDButList = new List<Button>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GenerateButtons(60);
        SetButtons(page);
    }

    private void GenerateButtons(decimal number)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            Button a = new Button();
            a.Text = "But" + i;
            MDButList.Add(a);
        }
        pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(number / 14));
    }



    private void SetButtons(int page)
    {
        labPageNum.Text = page.ToString() + " / " + pageCount.ToString();
        int ButPosX = 2; 
        int ButPosY = 2; 
        for (int i = panMDItems.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            panMDItems.Controls[i].Dispose();

        int upperlimit=(page * 14) - 1;
        if (upperlimit>MDButList.Count-1) upperlimit=MDButList.Count-1;

        for (int i = (page-1) * 14; i <=upperlimit ; i++)
        {
            Button NewPOBut = MDButList[i]; 

            SetPOButPos(ref ButPosX, ref ButPosY, ref NewPOBut);
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                ButPosX = 2;
                ButPosY += NewPOBut.Height + 10;
            }
            else
            {
                ButPosX += NewPOBut.Width + 10;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetPOButPos(ref int ButPosX, ref int ButPosY, ref Button NewPOBut)
    {
        NewPOBut.Location = new Point(ButPosX, ButPosY);
        panMDItems.Controls.Add(NewPOBut);
    }

    private void btnPrevPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (page > 1) page--;
        SetButtons(page);
    }

    private void btnNextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (page < pageCount) page++;
        SetButtons(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: Haha I was just upto the prev and next page functionality and I am going to borrow some of that to do it thanks! Giving you the answer as only one which attempted the question, and you did help ;)

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** call Controls.Clear() without disposing the controls.

Comment: You are completly right @HansPassant , my fault. I edited the answer.